# How do I send a token to Backend service from Azure API manangement

Tags: jwt, azure-functions, azure-api-management

How do I pass a token to a backend service from API management with this policy? I have a C# azure function (http-trigger) that acts like an api, to access it users need to have a valid jwt token, I have that working fine. but I cannot seem to send the jwt token to the backend service.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <openid-config *******************************/>
        <audiences>
            <audience>***********************</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>******************</issuer>
        </issuers>
    </validate-jwt>
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392067/azure-api-gateway-sending-a-jwt-token-to-the-backend

Comment: @codebrane I tried that, but it's still not sending the jwt to the back end

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [forward-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest) to send your HTTP request to your `backend` service?

```
<backend>
  <forward-request />
</backend>
```

Comment: I tried that, it does not seem to work

Comment: Could you provide some trace of your current implementation, @johnsondubula?

Comment: when I print the claims, these are the only two that are sent to the backend http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid   apim-MyAPIManangement        
http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/authlevel   Function

Answer (score 0):

What worked was this

```
<value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization"))</value>
```

Comment: And where did you add that? That would be really helpful to know!